# O que seria um ditongo? e tritongo?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, fonemas

O que seria na língua portuguesa um ditongo e um tritongo?

Como eles são ou estão classificados?

Existe diferença do `pt-pt` para o `pt-br` em relação a isso?

Comment: Basicamente um ditongo distingue-se de um hiato por haver apenas um esforço de voz. Repara na diferença entre "ai" (interjeição) e "A.I." (sigla).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ditongos, tritongos e hiatos são Encontros Vocálicos, isto é, são agrupamentos de vogais e semivogais, sem consoantes intermediárias.

> **Ditongo:**
>
> Encontro de uma vogal e de uma semivogal na mesma sílaba. Exemplos:
>
> - **Crescente**: quando a semivogal vem antes da vogal:   fér-r**eo**, au-sên-c**ia**, sé-r**ie**
> - **Decrescente**: quando a vogal vem antes da semivogal:   c**ai**-xa, l**ei**, pas-t**éi**s
>
> Além dos ditongos crescentes e decrescentes, existem mais 2 subtipos:
>
> - **Oral**: quando o ar sai só pela boca:   p**ai**, sé-r**ie**, his-tó-r**ia**
> - **Nasal**: quando o ar sai pela boca e pelo nariz:   m**ãe**, m**ui**-to, c**ãi**-bra

---

> 2) Tritongo
>
> Quando uma, semivogal, uma vogal e outra semivogal, sempre nessa
>   ordem, se encontram em uma só sílaba. Pode ser oral ou nasal. Exemplos:
>
> Sa-g**uão** - *Tritongo nasal*
>
> A-ve-ri-g**uei**- *Tritongo oral*

---

> 3) Hiato   Quando duas vogais da mesma palavra, mas de sílabas
>   diferentes se encontram. Exemplos:
>
> La-g**o-a**, F**a-í**s-ca, V**o-o**

E eu acho que são as mesmas regras tanto no `pt-BR` quanto no `pt-PT`.

Comment: Não entendi bem o que você quis dizer com "uma vez que nunca há mais de uma vogal numa sílaba"   Sera que sua intenção foi dizer que nas duas sílabas que contem as vogais formadoras do hiato só existe um vogal em cada uma?  O que dizer de "frei-o", "paraguai-o", "mei-o" ?

Comment: Erro meu, desculpe...

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que sei as definições são iguais no Português do Brasil e no Português de Portugal.

### di·ton·go

> substantivo masculino
>
> 1. [Fonética]  Reunião de dois sons vocálicos numa só sílaba (ex.: ai, ão, ei, eu, iu, õe, oi, ui).
>
> ditongo crescente • [Fonética]  Aquele que é composto por uma
> semivogal seguida de uma vogal (como ua em quatro ou ia em ária).
>
> ditongo decrescente • [Fonética]  Aquele que é composto por uma vogal
> seguida de uma semivogal (como ei em reinado ou eu em pneu).
>
> "ditongo", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/ditongo [consultado em
> 06-08-2015].

## tri·ton·go

> substantivo masculino
>
> Conjunto de três vogais que se pronunciam de um só jacto de voz .
>
> "tritongo", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/tritongo [consultado em
> 06-08-2015].

Comment: Feio tem duas sílabas, assim como raio.  Em um tritongo as três vogais estão em uma mesma sílaba.

Comment: @Centaurus tens razão, está mal no dicionário e eu confie.

Comment: @JorgeB. Está mal no dicionário? Onde? Não vejo... (mandei um email para lá e eles corrigiram ;)

Comment: @ANeves muito bem :)