# Porque a palavra "Feijão" tem duas sílabas e não três?

Tags: etimologia, divisão-silábica

No silabário, a palavra feijão está dividida: fei-jão.

Mas a família silábica do "F" é `fa fe fi fo fu fão`. A sílaba `fei` não faz parte desta família.

Porque a divisão é deste modo? Não deveria ser fe-i-jão?

Comment: Ela tem duas sílabas porque lê-se e fala-se fei-jão.  Se estivesse dividida em fe-i-jão, teria três sílabas. E se estivesse dividida em fe-i-jã-o teria 4 sílabas.  Mas nós dizemos fei-jão, portanto ela tem duas sílabas.  Espero que tenhas entendido.

Comment: possible duplicate of [O que seria um ditongo? e tritongo?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/762/o-que-seria-um-ditongo-e-tritongo)

Comment: @DanGetz relacionado, sim, mas não duplicata. Por favor remova a flag.

Comment: @Mindwin parece-me que a pergunta devia ser se a sílaba "fei" existe ou não.

Comment: @ANeves o entendimento sobre a pergunta evolui a medida que a discussão em torno dela também o faz. No momento em que foi escrita, foi a melhor articulação que consegui para o dilema a minha frente.

Comment: As sílabas com ditongos não são mostradas nas "famílias silábicas" porque seriam sílabas demais a ser listadas, porque praticamente qualquer combinação de vogal ("a" /a/, "é" /E/, "ê" /e/, "i" /i/, "ó" /O/, "ô" /o/, "u" /u/) com semivogal ("i" /j/, "u" /w/) é possível: `fa fai fau fé féi féu fê féi fêi fi fiu fó fói fóu fô fôi fôu fu fui`. Isso para não falar em tritongos como "fuai" que é fonologicamente possível no português (embora eu não sei se essa sílaba específica ocorra em alguma palavra).

Comment: Esqueci de listar também as nasais, como o `ão` de `fão` /ãw/ e também seria possível ter `fãe` /ãj/, como na palavra "mãe". Note também que, foneticamente, cada uma das sílabas "fe" e "fo" é na verdade duas, com a respectiva vogal aberta e fechada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É porque *feijão* ( /f**ej**.ˈʒ**ɐ̃w̃**/ ) tem dois [ditongos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology#Oral_diphthongs) e não tem outras vogais além daqueles ditongos; portanto tem apenas duas sílabas.

Comment: @Centaurus Contemplando a informação constante na pergunta, é possível deduzir que "feijão" tem duas sílabas. Na minha opinião, é só um problema de ambiguidade gerado pela explicação muito curta.

Answer (score 5):

As vogais são os fonemas sonoros produzidos por uma corrente de ar que passa livremente pela boca e/ou fossas nasais. Toda sílaba deve possuir pelo menos uma vogal (núcleo da sílaba) ou vogal + semivogal.

Na palavra fei-jão ocorrem dois ditongos (encontro de vogal + semivogal):

> **fei** - ditongo decrescente e oral
>   **jão** - ditongo decrescente e nasal

Observe que na sílaba "fei" produzimos apenas um som, não é necessário interromper o ar que passa pela boca, ou seja, não falamos "fe-i-jão".

Referências
http://www.jurisway.org.br/v2/pergunta.asp?idmodelo=7531
http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/fono/fono2.php

Comment: Não estou convencido acerca da frase final: na palavra "feio" também não precisamos de interromper o ar, e tem 2 sílabas; não mais que na palavra "quais", que só tem 1.

Comment: O movimento da língua é diferente, veja a palavra fei-o do seu exemplo:
fei: vogais anteriores "e" e "i", fonema /e/ e /i/ respectivamente (língua em direção ao palato);
o: vogal posterior, fonema /o/ (língua em direção ao véu palatino).
Referência ALMEIDA, Nilson Teixeira de. Gramática da Língua Portuguesa. 9 ed. São Paulo: Saraiva, 2009.

Comment: @ANeves Realmente não há interrupção, então eu diria que “feio” tem dois **pulsos**: [1] fêi [2] iú, por isso duas sílabas. O “i” é fraco (semivogal) e “gruda” nas vogais adjacentes, mas o “e” e o “o” formam centros de sílabas.