# Quais são as regras de acentuação de hiatos e ditongos?

Tags: ortografia, fonemas, acentuação

Acentuam-se todas as oxítonas terminadas em: -a(s), -e(s), -o(s), -em e -ens.

Entretanto, os ditongos tônicos a seguir são acentuados:

> Escarcéu, pinéu, mausoléu, etc.

Também são acentuados os hiatos:

> País, concluí, baú, etc.

São exceções à regra geral?

Como a acentuação de hiatos, ditongo e tritongos interferem nas regras de acentuação?

Quais são as regras de acentuação de hiatos e ditongos?

Comment: Related: [O que seria um ditongo? e tritongo?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/762/o-que-seria-um-ditongo-e-tritongo)

Comment: Ditongo é o encontro de uma vogal e uma semivogal (ou vice-versa) numa mesma sílaba. Exemplo: sé-rie (i = semivogal, e = vogal); pai (a = vogal, i = semivogal).

Tritongo é a sequência formada por uma semivogal, uma vogal e uma semivogal, sempre nessa ordem, numa só sílaba. Pode ser oral ou nasal. Exemplos: Paraguai - Tritongo oral; quão - Tritongo nasal. Referência: http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/fono/fono3.php

Comment: Denis só fiz referência aquela pergunta para quem não souber o que é, não era preciso responder ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Escarcéu", "pinéu", etc. são acentuadas para marcar o "e" aberto; ler-se-ão assim /ɛw/ e não /ew/ (como "céu", não como "seu").

Pode ler-se no Acordo Ortográfico de 1990 ([Base VIII](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&id=8-1&version=1990)):

> 1. Acentuam-se com acento agudo:
>      [...]
>      d) As palavras oxítonas com os ditongos abertos grafados *-éi*, *éu* ou *ói*, podendo estes dois últimos ser seguidos ou não de *-s*: *anéis*, *batéis*, *fiéis*, *papéis*; *céu(s)*, *chapéu(s)*, *ilhéu(s)*, *véu(s)*; *corrói* (de *corroer*), *herói(s)*, *remói* (de *remoer*), *sóis*.

Já o caso da acentuação de *i* e *u* em vogais tónicas de palavras oxítonas paroxítonas é coberta na [Base X](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990#10-list). Em particular, as palavras indicadas ("país", "concluí", baú") são cobertas pelo [ponto 1](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&id=10-1&version=1990):

> As vogais tónicas/tônicas grafadas *i* e *u* das palavras oxítonas e paroxítonas levam acento agudo quando antecedidas de uma vogal com que não formam ditongo e desde de que não constituam sílaba com a eventual consoante seguinte, excetuando o caso de s: *adaís* (pl. de *adail*), *aí*, *atraí* (de *atrair*), *baú*, [...], *país*, etc.; [...].

---

Comment: Não percebo uma coisa. Nos ***i*** e ***u*** tónicos não se deviam excluir os que são seguidos de ***nh***, como *rainha, bainha*?

Comment: Olha-me esta! Vem no ponto 2. Diz que em *bainha, rainha, moinho* o ***i*** forma sílaba com ***nh***! Não tou a ver como.De acordo com o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/bainha) não forma.

Comment: Sim, também não percebi essa. O [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/bainha) também indica três sílabas.

Comment: Há uma [pergunta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1536/157) que procura esclarecer esta dúvida que o Jacinto levantou.