# Em "rainha" o "i" forma sílaba com o "nh"? O Acordo Ortográfico diz que sim!

Tags: divisão-silábica

[O acordo ortográfico, Base X, ponto 2](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990#10-list), diz que na palavra ***rainha*** o ***i*** forma sílaba com o ***nh***! Ora eu sempre pensei que a divisão silábica de *rainha* fosse ***ra.i.nha***. E na verdade é isso que diz o [Aulete digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/bainha) e o [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/rainha). Alguém me explica então o significado de ***i*** formar sílaba com ***nh*** em ***rainha***?

O mesmo se passa com palavras como *bainha, moinho, remoinho*, etc.. Isto é relevante para a acentuação de ***i*** e ***u*** precedido de vogal com a qual não formam ditongo, [assunto discutido nesta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1534/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-regras-de-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-hiatos-e-ditongos).

Comment: Esta [resposta](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/rainha-sem-acento-no-i/10443) do ciberduvidas vai na mesma linha, dizendo que existe um [j̃] que pertence à primeira mas nasalado pela segunda.

Comment: O artigo diz que o ***nh*** está na sílaba seguinte. Será então que é como se o ***n*** estivesse ao mesmo na sílaba do ***i*** para o nazalar e na sílaba do ***nha***? Parece-me de qualquer modo imprecisa a linguagem do AO. Ou será que é gíria consagrada entre linguistas?

Comment: Acho que é o Ciberdúvidas que tem um erro e não o acordo. Ainda consigo admitir "ra.inha", mas agora "rai.nha"...

Comment: Segundo o Ciberdúvidas é *ra.i.nha*. Eles dizem que o ***nh*** na sílaba seguinte faz o ***i*** formar sílaba por si próprio. Acho que uma sílaba *inha* não faria parte da nossa tradição de divisão silábica.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu entendo que o Acordo Ortográfico diz que o i de `rainha` se agrega à consoante seguinte, e por isso se lê `ra·in·nha` em vez de `rai·nha`.
O mesmo efeito seria obtido pondo um acento no i (`ra·í·nha`), como discutido nesta pergunta relacionada que referes: [Quais são as regras de acentuação de hiatos e ditongos?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1534/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-regras-de-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-hiatos-e-ditongos)

Neste caso, como o i já evita a formação de ditongo ao "colar-se" à consoante seguinte, deixa de ser necessário adicionar o acento.

> As vogais tónicas/tônicas grafadas i e u das palavras oxítonas e paroxítonas não levam acento agudo quando, antecedidas de vogal com que não formam ditongo, constituem sílaba com **a consoante seguinte**, como é o caso de nh, l, m, n, r e z: bainha, moinho, rainha; adail, paul, Raul; Aboim, Coimbra, ruim; ainda, constituinte, oriundo, ruins, triunfo; atrair, demiurgo, influir, influirmos; juiz, raiz, etc.

Portanto, de acordo com a minha leitura deste [ponto 2 da Base X do acordo ortográfico](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990), estas palavras leem-se não com o i a formar ditongo com a vogal que o precede, mas com a consoante que lhe segue:

- ba·i**n**·nha, mo·i**n**·nho, ra·i**n**·nha;
- a·da·il, pa·ul, Ra·ul;
- A·bo·im, Co·im·bra, ru·im;
- a·in·da, cons·ti·tu·in·te, o·ri·un·do, ru·ins, tri·un·fo; a·tra·ir, de·mi·ur·go, in·flu·ir, in·flu·ir·mos;
- ju·iz, ra·iz,
- etc

O meu entendimento, no caso de `rainha` e outros `-inh-`, é que o i forma uma sílaba anasalada com o apoio do nh que se lhe segue: `ra·in·nha` ou `ra·inh·nha` ou `ra·im·nha`, `mo·in·nho` ou `mo·inh·nho` ou `mo·im·nho`, etc.

Comment: _nh_ é uma consoante não, duas.

Comment: @Artefacto sim, mas compare com *oriu**nd**o*: «n» e «d» são duas consoantes separadas, mas o «n» não faz o mesmo papel do que o «d»: em vez de ser consoante fonética, combina com o «u» para ficar /ũ/. A consoante «nh», apesar de ser uma consoante só, desempenha duas funções no mesmo tempo em *rainha*, como fosse *"raim-nha". Então «constituem sílaba com a consoante seguinte» pode ser mal-escrito, mas de alguma forma refere a esta situação: o «i» forma uma sílaba, mas não é a sílaba /i/: é a sílaba /ĩ/, precisamente por causa duma "combinação" com a consoante seguinte «nh».

Comment: @Artefacto, a intenção do teu comentário é pouco clara. A edição corrige o que quiseste apontar? Se não, podes clarificar?

Comment: Eu percebi a ideia, mas parece haver uma contradição entre "se agrega à consoante seguinte, e por isso se lê ra·in·nha" e o texto do acordo: "constituem sílaba com a consoante seguinte, como é o caso de nh". Talvez substituindo o parágrafo inicial com o final e usar "ĩ" em vez de "in" ficasse a resposta mais clara.

Comment: Já agora, se é isso que o acordo quer dizer, está muito pouco claro. Especialmente se considerarmos que de facto "constituem sílaba com a consoante seguinte" nos outros casos.

Comment: ANeves, também tinha passado esta ideia pela cabeça, mas concordo com o @Artefacto que se é isto que o AO quer dizer, deveria tê-lo feito de forma mais clara.

Comment: Também concordo que se é isto que queriam dizer, o disseram de forma muito pouco clara. Quero incluir isto na resposta.

Comment: ANeves, não queres incluir a fonte e link da citação?

Comment: @Jacinto era o ponto 2 da base X do A.O. de que a pergunta trata. Adicionei a citação.

Comment: Um bom exemplo para isto que o @Seninha disse, é a palavra *muito*. Se houvesse correspondência direta entre ortografia e fonologia, teria de se escrever * "*muinto*".

Comment: @Seninha podes sempre escrever o comentário de novo, e apagar o antigo. :)

Comment: A hifenização (separação silábica ortográfica) não precisa necessariamente ser igual à silabificação (separação silábica fonética), pois a ortografia nem sempre representa bijetivamente a fonologia, i.e., nem sempre há a relação um-para-um de um grafema/sinal gráfico para um fonema/característica fonética e vice-versa. No caso de **ra-i-nha**, há uma relação de um-para-dois: um grafema (`⟨nh⟩`) para duas características fonéticas em sílabas diferentes (`/◌̃/` numa sílaba, e `/ɲ/` noutra).

Answer (score 5):

Não existem sílabas com dois sons de vogal, pelo menos em português; assim, “inha” nunca pode ser uma só sílaba.

A divisão silábica correta é **ra.i.nha**.

Aliás, a língua é primeiramente falada e só depois escrita, e por isso a escrita segue a fala (por vezes com algum atraso). Tente dizer “rainha” mantendo “inha” numa só sílaba… Conseguiu? Eu não. :) Se ninguém consegue dizer “inha” como uma só sílaba, também não é possível dizer que na escrita “inha” constitui uma sílaba.

O [Portal da Língua Portuguesa](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/about.html?action=syllables) dá uma definição teórica:

> A divisão silábica consiste na identificação e delimitação das sílabas de cada palavra. As sílabas têm como constituinte obrigatório uma vogal, que determina o seu núcleo ou elemento central. Essa vogal pode ou não vir acompanhada de uma outra vogal, foneticamente chamada semivogal, formando um ditongo, como acontece na palavra *cau*.sa. O núcleo da sílaba pode ser precedido de uma ou mais consoantes, como em *pla*.no, e seguido de uma ou mais consoantes, como em *pers*.pe.ti.va.

Não tenho explicação para aquilo que no Acordo Ortográfico à primeira vista me parece uma *gaffe*. Pessoalmente, aceito a explicação do Ciberdúvidas.

Comment: Só falta aqui uma justificação para rainha se ler `ra·i·nha`, e não `rai·nha` como peito se lê `pei·to` ou raia se lê `rai·a`.

Answer (score 3):

É importante lembrar, como foi dito acima, que a ortografia é apenas um conjunto de convenções sobre a **escrita**. Muitas vezes, portanto, ortografia nada tem a ver com a língua *per se*. Fonologicamente, a divisão silábica mais provável é `ra.i.nha', por diversas razões. Ortograficamente, regras arbitrárias podem ser criadas que façam com que a silabificação "oficial" desvie daquilo que deveria ser.

## Mas...

Apenas como contraponto, vou expor aqui uma possível razão linguística para a ortografia proposta.

Segmentos como `nh` ou `lh` são, muitas vezes, tratados como complexos em fonologia. São, por exemplo, mais "pesados" do que seus respectivos segmentos simples (`n`, `l`). Existem motivações independentes para essa conclusão (muitas delas vindas dos padrões acentuais da língua).

Com base nisso, muitas análises fonológicas partem do princípio de que `nh` é, na verdade, uma consoante geminada ("dupla" no nível suprasegmental), e que, portanto, está presente em duas sílabas ao mesmo tempo: ra.iN.Ha. Teoricamente, isso torna a sílaba penúltima pesada, o que explicaria por que não temos palavras proparoxítonas com `nh` ou `lh` nas sílabas final ou penúltima.

Por exemplo, não temos em português palavras como `pátalho`, e essa explicação dá conta dessa lacuna na língua. A explicação também é motivada com base em outras línguas, onde segmentos como `lh` ou `nh` se comportam de forma diferenciada. Foneticamente, ambos são (mais) complexos relativo a segmentos simples (e.g., têm mais duração e envolvem mais complexidade articulatória).

Comment: Queres dizer «está presente em duas sílabas ao mesmo tempo: _**ra.iN.NHa»?**_ Achas então que é isso que o AO quer dizer com _**i** formar sílaba com **nh?**_

Answer (score 1):

O acordo ortográfico está mal redigido nesse ponto.

De facto o caso do NH é excecional, pois ao contrário dos outros casos, a vogal tónica não faz sílaba com a consoante procedente.

O motivo para se ter optado por não utilizar acento gráfico nestas situações é o facto de não haver ditongos que precedam um NH.

Comment: Pois, também me parece que eles se explicaram mal.

Comment: Os "outros casos" que referes no segundo parágrafo são coisas como *ainda, paiz, ruim, ruir,* não?