# Existe alguma palavra "quadritongo", no português?

Tags: fonologia, vogais

Primeiramente, acho que não existe a palavra "quadritongo", mas a usarei para facilitar.

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma palavra "quadritongo", em Português, como, — acho eu — "uruguaio".
Acho que, mesmo se não existir, palavras como "uruguaio" podem ser faladas como um "quadritongo", na fala rápida.

Comment: Tem um cara que tem um sobrenome sendo "Paião", mas não consigo decidir a organização das sílabas ou se tem sílabas... Fica aí pra você, se não tiver sílabas temos a primeira palavra quadritonga no português encontrada com sucesso!

Comment: Groen o Imperador, obrigado pela sugestão, por mais que isso não seja uma resposta e, sim, um comentário. A divisão silábica seria pai-ão ou pa-ião. O problema de usar nomes próprio é que podemos inventar um com a pronúncia que nos prouver ou achar algum nalguma língua que tenha “quadritongo”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Não existe a palavra "quadritongo" em português.
   Mas mesmo não existindo, faz sentido. Pode-se perfeitamente usá-la.
2. Uma palavra em si não é um ditongo, tritongo, ou quadritongo. A palavra *tem* ditongos, tritongos, ou quadritongos.
3. Mas "uruguaio" não tem um quadritongo. Tem um tritongo (uai).

## Explicando

Para mais informação, consulta esta pergunta:

- [O que seria um ditongo? e tritongo?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/762/o-que-seria-um-ditongo-e-tritongo)

### Ditongo

Um ditongo são duas vogais ditas na mesma sílaba:

- P**ai** tem uma sílaba, duas vogais na mesma sílaba fazem um ditongo (ai).
- A·í tem duas sílabas, não tem um ditongo mas dois "unitongos".
- P**oi**s tem uma sílaba, duas vogais na mesma sílaba fazem um ditongo (oi).

### Tritongo

Um tritongo são três vogais na mesma sílaba:

- Sa·g**uão** - tritongo nasal
- A·ve·ri·g**uei**- tritongo oral

## Quadritongo

Um quadritongo precisaria de quatro vogais *na mesma sílaba*. Não conheço nenhum.

- U·ru·guai·o tem as quatro vogais em sílabas separadas, não tem um quadritongo. Tem um tritongo (uai).

Comment: ANeves, será que na fala rápida ou desatenta se pode ter quatro vogais na mesma silaba?

Comment: Deixo registrado o caso (cômico) de uma frase em Português (BR, informal) que só possui vogais, seria um _octatongo_ se pudéssemos ignorar os espaços: [ó o auê aí ó](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/%F3+o+au%EA+ai+%F3/)